# parsing dates with variable spaces

Tags: java, date, jodatime, simpledateformat

I am using Joda to parse dates and have a format where leading zeros are not used, e.g.:

```
 Mon Nov 20 14:40:36 2006
 Mon Nov  6 14:40:36 2006
```

Note that the dayOfMonth field is left-padded with a blank.

Currently I seem to have to use two different formats and reparse if one fails

```
"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy"
"EEE MMM  d HH:mm:ss yyyy"
```

Is there a single format (or an API switch) which deals with both cases? (is the answer the same for SimpleDateFormat - which I don't use?)

Comment: String = 03-09-2015 06:45: 00, s.replaceAll(":(\\s+)",":")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have just created a quick program to check this -

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy");

try {
    String source1 = "Mon Nov 20 14:40:36 2006";
    Date d1 = sdf.parse(source1);
    String source2 = "Mon Nov  6 14:40:36 2006";
    Date d2 = sdf.parse(source2);

    String res1 = sdf.format(d1);
    String res2 = sdf.format(d2);

    System.out.println(source1 +"="+ res1);
    System.out.println(source2 +"="+ res2);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output from this is -

```
Mon Nov 20 14:40:36 2006=Mon Nov 20 14:40:36 2006
Mon Nov  6 14:40:36 2006=Mon Nov 6 14:40:36 2006
```

So, even though source2 has the extra space, it is still parsed by

```
EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks very much - it is possible it's a difference between SimpleDateFormat and Joda

Answer (score 10):

### java.time and format pattern letter p

Here’s the modern answer, using java.time, the successor of Joda-Time.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM ppd HH:mm:ss uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);

    String[] stringsToParse = {
            "Mon Nov 20 14:40:36 2006",
            "Mon Nov  6 14:40:36 2006"
    };
    for (String dateTimeString : stringsToParse) {
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);
        System.out.println(dateTime);
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> 2006-11-20T14:40:36
> 2006-11-06T14:40:36
> ```

To `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern` format letter `p` means padding with spaces on the left. `pp` means padding to two position. It can be used for both formatting and — as here — parsing.

I know you asked about Joda-Time. The Joda-Time home page says:

> Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project.
>   No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate
>   to `java.time` (JSR-310).

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Documentation of `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)
- [Joda-Time - Home](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Comment: Many thanks. I didn't know about `java.time`. Will try to convert

Answer (score 5):

I tried using a single 'd' as suggested above in logstash 1.1.1 but it still complained about a malformed date when a single digit day with an extra leading space was parsed.  The following logstash rules did work.

```
timestamp => [ "MMM dd HH:mm:ss", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss" ]
```

It didn't matter which order the two date formats were in.  No more warnings were output once I added both formats.